# Extending htmloptionscollection

Tags: javascript, object

I have a code to extend the htmloptionscollection object:

```
HTMLOptionsCollection.prototype.contains = HTMLOptionsCollection.prototype.contains ||
    function(otherOption) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i].value === otherOption.value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
```

It works well on firefoxa dn in Opera but does not work in IE9 and in Google Chrome it shows:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLOptionsCollection is not defined"

How can I solve this problem. Am I doing anything wrong? If I am, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something wrong then the wrong thing is that you assume that the whole DOM is supported by any browser. For example IE: I don't see any prototype for HTMLOptionsCollection on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347057%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I assumed that the DOM specification http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#HTMLOptionsCollection was correct which is what I do with every single language. If I can't assume that a language follows its specification then I'll take a lot more to program in that language!!! So, what's the workaround for this problem? I want to extend the object that document.createElement('select').options returns.

Comment: It's not a problem of the DOM-specification, the problem is the application that doesn't follow. It should be possible to extend the HTMLSelectElement - prototype, but before you do anything like this read why you shouldn't to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826599/general-reasons-not-to-deal-with-documents-and-elements-prototype